# Why the weird language?

Tags: file, dll, ini

I love editing files in Windows or Android i goes to the system and choose a random DLL file or ini or dat and edit it to see his codes but don't make changes, anyways i love doing this but when i edit a dat file in Android or DLL in windows i find a weird cryptic icons and language.
its looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgJC9.jpg

So my question is why is this things there i mean they can just use scripts with normal understandable language i hope someone explain me this because i'm curious, and thanks!

Comment: That is not "weird language", that is compiled code being displayed as text which it can't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because DLLs are **compiled**. You're looking at binary data (machine code instructions, plus various bits of data) with a text editor. While some programs are distributed as source code (bash scripts, JavaScript/HTML/CSS Windows Universal Apps, several others), many others (probably "most" on Windows) are distributed as compiled machine code.